# How to compare object in an array before pushing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So, I want to do the following:

1. In a .each function, push the first object into an array X
2. Execute a function that compares 2nd object with the first already in, and if result < 100, push it, otherwise leave it out.
3. Do the same with the 3rd object (comparing with latest object in), 4th object (comparing with latest object in), nth object (comparing with n-1)...

At the end I want to have an array containing only objects whose comparison with the latest pushed object is < 100.

I imagine something like this:

```
 $(json.locations).each(function(key, value){

    var tempLocation = new L.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    if (locationArray.length < 1){ // push first object

        locationArray.push(tempLocation);
        counter++;

    }
    else{ // first object is in, the rest will be conditional on comparision 
        if (execute function, get result, if result > 100){
           locationArray.push(tempLocation);
           counter++;
        }
    }
```

Am I going in the right direction? Any tips?

The function to compare the objects looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (wop) {

Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
   return this * Math.PI / 180;
}

var lat2 = 42.741; 
var lon2 = -71.3161; 
var lat1 = 42.806911; 
var lon1 = -71.290611; 

var R = 637100; // km 
//has a problem with the .toRad() method below.
var x1 = lat2-lat1;
var dLat = x1.toRad();  
var x2 = lon2-lon1;
var dLon = x2.toRad();  
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
                Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c; 

if (d < 100){
    alert("This is close! " + d + " meters!");
}
else{
    alert("Far away!");
}
});
```

Where **lat1, lat2 and lng1, lng2** are the values to be fetched from the last object in and the one being compared.

## **EDIT**

Using the answer from **iam-decoder** I've gotten here:

```
var testLocation = function(location){

    Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
       return this * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    var lat1 = location.lat; 
    var lon1 = location.lng; 
    var lat2 = 42.806911; 
    var lon2 = -71.290611; 

    var R = 637100; // km 
    //has a problem with the .toRad() method below.
    var x1 = lat2-lat1;
    var dLat = x1.toRad();  
    var x2 = lon2-lon1;
    var dLon = x2.toRad();  
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
                    Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
                    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var distanceresult = R * c; 

    return distanceresult;
    console.log(distanceresult); // not working??
};


// iterate through the locations and create map markers for each location
$(json.locations).each(function(key, value){
    var latitude =  $(this).attr('latitude');
    var longitude = $(this).attr('longitude');
    var tempLocation = new L.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    if (locationArray.length < 1){
        locationArray.push(tempLocation);
        counter++;
    }
    else if(testLocation(tempLocation, locationArray[locationArray.length-1]) >= 100){
        console.log("good");  // tested the else if and it works.
    }
});
console.log(locationArray)
```

I tested the else if expression and it works (adding return 100 and return 101 in testlocation function).

The problem now is that **I don't really know how to pass the latitudes/longitudes from the last element in the array and from the new candidate** into the testlocation function to make the calculation.

How do I pass these variables from one function to the other??

Comment: Just write a function that takes 2 arguments when `locationArray.length > 1`? First argument is the n-th object and second is the n-1-th object? I suggest you do declare the function in the second code sample seperately and return a float (distance calculated). This float can easely checked for < 100

Comment: @martinweise thanks for the comment but I didn't really get it, I'm afraid I'm not quite at your level yet.. : /

Answer (score 1):

just create the anonymous function for comparison and store it in a variable:

```
var testLocation = function(location, compareTo){
    var result;
    //do something
    return result;
};
$(json.locations).each(function(key, value){
    var tempLocation = new L.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    if (locationArray.length < 1){ // push first object
        locationArray.push(tempLocation);
        counter++;
    } else if(testLocation(tempLocation, locationArray[locationArray.length-1]) > 100){
         locationArray.push(tempLocation);
         counter++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain this? Beginner alert : )
`if(testLocation(tempLocation, locationArray[locationArray.length-1]) > 100)`

Comment: Please see edit to see your solution on the works. Still unfinished though!

Comment: its already passing the last element from the array, you're just not accepting it in the function, change your first line to this: `var testLocation = function(location, compareTo){` and you can access the last element by using the `compareTo` variable inside that function

Answer (score -1):

As far as I see, you want to filter LonLats with a distance between them.

I imagine something like this:

```
var maxDistance = 100;
var filtered = [];

var compareAndPush = function(item) {
  if (filtered.length == 0) {
     filtered.push(item);
  } else {
     var distance = compareLonLats(item, filtered[filtered.length]);
     if (distance < maxDistance) {
        filtered.push(item);
     }
  }
}

$(json.locations).each(compareAndPush);
```

Plus put the compare process into a separate function called 'compareLonLats' or something like that.